# flask environment setup using subprocess

Tags: python-3.x, flask, subprocess

I have been trying to run the command
"export FLASK_APP=start.py"
&
"export FLASK_ENV=development"
using subprocess in python, not able to set this up, run this command directly in command prompt works.

```
subp = subprocess.check_call('export FLASK_APP=start.py', shell=True,
                stdin=None, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=None, close_fds=True)
```

see the command **export FLASK_APP=start.py**

this is not working. can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows, the environment variable syntax depends on command-line interpreter. On Command Prompt

```
C:\path\to\app>set FLASK_APP=start.py
```

And on PowerShell:

```
C:\path\to\app> $env:FLASK_APP = "start.py"
```

so basically if you're using windows just replace **export** with **set**.
Also, I'd suggest you to create a separate file within the folder called **.env**.
and within the file type the following line.

```
FLASK_ENV=development
```

save it.

hopefully, this should do the job!

```
set FLASK_APP=start.py
set FLASK_ENV=development
flask run
```

try running the above commands. I hope this solves your problem !

Comment: No, I am using ubuntu.

Comment: Also, the command.. I have to run through subprocess library of python..  as this is kind of automation for flask, and the python script needs to run that